# Status bar on few iOS devices showing in white

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, statusbar, hockeyapp

Content in the Status bar on iOS devices showing in white on some devices like iPhone 5 iOS 7.1.2  and iOS 8.2. On other devices it is black (as expected). (background is white)

In info.plist I have set View controller-based status bar appearance to NO.

The catch is I am seeing issue only when it build from jenkins and pushed via Hockeyapp distribution.

I have tried building using distribution config on local but unable to reproduce on simulator or above devices which has issues.

Answer (score 0):

Set the `UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance` to `YES` in the
    `.plist` file.

In the viewDidLoad do a `[self setNeedsStatusBarAppearanceUpdate];`

In AppDelegate.m, add the following.

```
 -(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions{

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setStatusBarStyle:UIStatusBarStyleLightContent];

    }
```